# installing and running redis with homebrew

Tags: redis, homebrew

I've installed redis with

`brew install redis`

I then start it with

`brew services start redis`

However when run

`redis-cli ping`

I get:

`Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

When I run

`brew services list`

I get:

`Name              Status  User  Plist
redis             started clint /Users/clint/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist`

But when I look in the system.log in Console.app I see this every 10 seconds:

`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.redis[85774]): Service could not initialize: 17C205: xpcproxy + 11572 [1522][1729AB5E-4591-3F1B-AC72-36700ABA4F74]: 0xd
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.redis): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

When I looked in the `/Users/clint/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist` I found it was pointing to the logs dir at `/usr/local/var/log`. The permissions on that folder were wrong.  After doing a `chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/**` redis started up immediately.

Comment: Same problem but in my case /opt/homebrew/var/log/redis.log was root:admin